# Loading the SavedModel in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

While running `//tensorflow/c:c_api_test` test on a **big endian machine**, the test fails while reading the SavedModel in sub test [SavedModel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.2.1/tensorflow/c/c_api_test.cc#L1179).

The test failure log is as below:

```
2017-06-29 09:04:34.080751: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:226]   
Loading SavedModel from: <dir>/.cache/bazel/_bazel_test/24685d064c07f7346b48c2d13ec3ad69/execroot/tensorflow/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/tensorflow/c/c_api_test.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/testdata/half_plus_two/00000123  
2017-06-29 09:04:34.083793: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:145]   
Restoring SavedModel bundle.   
2017-06-29 09:04:34.087103: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Unimplemented: Reading a bundle with different endianness from the reader   
2017-06-29 09:04:34.087445: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Unimplemented: Reading a bundle with different endianness from the reader   
2017-06-29 09:04:34.088046: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Unimplemented: Reading a bundle with different endianness from the reader   

2017-06-29 09:04:34.088227: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:274] Loading SavedModel: fail. Took 7493 microseconds. tensorflow/c/c_api_test.cc:1265: Failure
          Expected: TF_OK
          Which is: 0 To be equal to: TF_GetCode(s)
          Which is: 12
```

Is there a way to convert the above SavedModel to Big Endian while reading in this test case?

What would be appropriate way to resolve this test failure?